# Is it possible to Recorder an Audio from a Web page without Flash Media Server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, audio, red5

a lot of the people who talk about Record an Audio from Web Page said that you have to use Server Side Applications Like RED5, Wowza, Adobe Flash Media Servers.

**But Is it possible to record an audio from client side Flash Only?**

**Yes, it is possible to record an audio from client side Flash Only.**
in the modern versions of Flash you can do that, it will save the audio first in your memory and then you can upload it to your server without need for a Flash Media Server.

and here is an example of that :  http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/barebonesRecorder/

and i configure the client version here http://alkobair.com/trial/ and **it works Great**.

**My Question is :**

Do you know another Client Side Flash Audio Recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's possible with flash 10.1. See the "**Look, Ma - no server!**" section in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140101002913/http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/) page of recorders examples. There is some source code there. too.

Comment: The author of that link took the content down.

Comment: Thanks Octavian. I've found a snapshot [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140101002913/http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/) in the Archive.org Wayback Machine.